# Jquery .val() change the variable value by pressing the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass the value of the limit in Jquery at the touch of a button. I almost found a solution, but can not quite understand. How to set the value to "limit:" the default and change it by pressing the button.

HTML

```
<button id="pagelimit default">1</button>
<button id="pagelimit">2</button>
<button id="pagelimit">3</button>

</div>
```

JS

```
function displayVals() {
var pagelim = $( "#pagelimit" ).val();
};

$('#product-grid').mixItUp({
pagination: {
    limit: $pagelim // insert button value
}
});
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: instead of initializing var `pagelim` inside `displayVals` give it a global scope.

Answer (score 1):

ID of an element must be unique... It looks like you want to update the `limit` option with the clicked button's text so

```
<button class="pagelimit default">1</button>
<button class="pagelimit">2</button>
<button class="pagelimit">3</button>
```

then

```
//this method is not used in the below code as we don't know which button was clicked here... if you share how the `displayVals` method is called then we can try to make this work
function displayVals() {
    var pagelim = $("#pagelimit").val();
};

jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.pagelimit').click(function () {
        //update the limit option
        $('#product-grid').mixItUp('setOptions', {
            limit: +$(this).text()
        });
    });

    //initialize the plugin
    $('#product-grid').mixItUp({
        pagination: {
            limit: 1
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: You need to have some element with ID "pagelimit" somewhere for this to work, maybe a hidden text field.

Comment: 'displayVals' method from the example on the page [link](http://api.jquery.com/val/#example-0).

Comment: @RQEST is that how you have wrote it... like an event handler... can you share how you have used it

Comment: The fact that I do not know how to use it properly, because I almost do not know JS